# Are MobX actions allowed to show a confirm dialog, or navigate to a new screen? More generally, can actions touch ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flutter, mobx, mobx-react

I am refactoring MobX in **large-scale** applications. Since it is big, making the code clean is very important.

There is an `action` that does the following (simplified):

```
@action myAction() {
  var data = await api.getSomeDataFromServer();
  
  if (data.warnUser) {
    var userAgrees = await showConfirmDialog('Hey, are you really sure?'); // #1
    if (!userAgrees) return;
  }

  someOperations(data);

  Navigator.push('/another_page'); // #2
}
```

I am worried whether the `#1` and `#2` are OK or not. The reason is that, IMHO mobx has a `UI - action - state` triad (as is seen in the figure below by the mobx book). Thus, `Action`s should modify the `State` instead of the `UI` directly. But in `#1`, the `Action` directly shows a dialog - which is `UI`; in `#2`, the `Action` directly navigates to another page - which is also UI related.

In short, can MobX's `action`s directly "touch" and manipulate the `ui`s?

I have made some searches about this and is quite confused now. Thanks for any suggestions!

Remark: I tag it as both Flutter and JavaScript, because indeed I am using Flutter but this question applies to the JS version of MobX as well.

Remark: Following is the diagram from the mobx book.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main advantages of Mobx is making the state and UI completely decoupled. By decoupling the state from the UI, your tests will be far easier to write. The example you posted, would be very hard to test.

I had projects where I would write the complete application business logic without starting to work on the UI at all, then I would just hook the state and state-changing methods to the UI.

Also because Mobx works with flutter and Javascript by decoupling the UI from state management, you could port the complete business logic to Javascript and vice versa.
So to conclude, your code works but it's not the *Mobx way* :)

For example, you could [mobx reaction](https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html#reaction) to **react**  to state changes.

```js
@action myAction() {
  // if myAction is a method on JS class
  this.data = await api.getSomeDataFromServer();
}
```

Then somewhere in you UI code

```js
reaction(
    () => myClassInstance.data, // when data changes
    data => { //<- run this function
  
     if (data.warnUser) {
       var userAgrees = await showConfirmDialog(); // #1
       if (!userAgrees) return;
     }

    someOperations(data);

    Navigator.push('/another_page'); // #2
    }
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So could you please suggest how to write it in the correct way?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! I will think about it.